# What SAN value is 'one fifth of current sanity' measured against to determine indefinite insanity?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e, sanity

The rules for Indefinite Insanity state that it kicks in after a character loses…

> a fifth or more of current Sanity points in one game “day”

Given that SAN loss might be occurring at various intervals throughout the day, what is the *‘current sanity’* against which *‘one fifth’* is measured? Is it the character's SAN at the **start** of the day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it the character's SAN at the start of the day?

Yes, it is a good idea to keep track and calculate the 20% at the beginning of each "day" (which doesn't have to be a 24h period between 00:00 and 12:00, but rather a narrative time unit).

An even better idea is to have the players keep track of it, because that's a lot of bookkeeping.